# How can I quickly solve this query?

Tags: sql

I have one table which contains 3 fields namely code, name, rperson. It has following data:

```
code name    rperson
100  anil    100
101  babu    100
102  sajad   100
103  Rajesh  102
104  roy     102
```

I want a table with following output:

```
name   rperson
anil   anil
babu   anil
sajad  anil
Rajesh sajad 
roy    sajad
```

Comment: I might be wrong but please do your homework / interview quiz yourself.

Comment: You need a self join.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.name as name,b.name as represon from table1 a 
inner join table1 b on a.code=b.rperson
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear ..
But from what i understood u may get the result using this
select t2.name,(select name from table t where t2.rperson= t.code) from table t2